# D-Link Wireless N 150 USB Adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi

Link DWA-123 wireless adapter, on my desktop running Ubuntu 9.10 the device is being recognized as in, when I hit lsusb i get this entry

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2001:3c17 D-Link Corp. [hex]
```

How do i get this working so that i can connect it to my wireless network at home?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have such device so I cannot test it, but I guess if you install new version of Ubuntu it will just work.

Ubuntu 9.10 is quite old. This month the 12.04 LTS will be released. You can download [beta2](http://releases.ubuntu.uasw.edu/precise/) iso, burn it, and test it.

Good luck.

Comment: Right, not only old but *unsupported* -- the [upcoming **LTS** release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_9.10#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (= long term support, @Aadi Droid) is a valuable hint.

Comment: my system is old, that is why i was running an older version. I have Ubuntu 11.10 but the installation file runs unity by default because of which system hangs on installation.

Comment: Try unity2d. Also try some boot options like disable APIC, etc. If it fails too, then you can install from alternate CD (regular installer, not a LiveCD with install option).

Comment: wait so if i understand right, ubuntu 9.10 does not support this device ?

Comment: @AadiDroid I don't know. But you have bigger chances that newer Ubuntu does support it.

Comment: alright will try installing Ubuntu 11.10, i could test is before trying it on my wooden comp, I have my laptop running Ubuntu 11.10